# HTML: How do I center a banner in a table?

Tags: html, image, center

I have not used HTML in a long time (pre-CSS). Basically I am a complete noob. I pray that I can get some useful information.

There are threads that cover this question and I have employed all of them without success, so I am assuming it is something in my style formatting, but I cannot pin point the issue. This is where I am right now.

{<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html14/frameset.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>A Web Site</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            border-style:ridge;
            border-color:inherit;
            border-width:thin;
            background-color: beige;
            margin-left: 4px;
            margin-right: 4px;
            margin-top:3px;
            margin-bottom:3px;
            padding: inherit;
            font-family: Calibri;
            height:auto;
            width:auto;

            </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div id="Home Page">
                <table>
                   <tr><td align="center">
                      <img src="Some/pic.jpg">
                   </td></tr>

                </table>
                </div>


   </form>
</body>
</html>}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a curly brace.

```
//...
height: auto;
width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also had to place the align="center" in the <table align="center"> tag. Apparently the <td> </td> inherits formatting from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Add a close curly brace after `width:auto;` as mentioned in the previous answer, add a close tag on the `<img>` like `</img>` (or lazy close `<img />`), and remove the close curly tag after `</html>`.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <div id="Home Page">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <img src="Some/pic.jpg" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your text in span tag and apply css's margin property to it. 
Like e.g

```
<span class="textCenter"> Hi This is text </span>
```

In CSS:

```
.textCenter {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

You can adjust the margin to center your text accordingly.
Check margin property here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp